# Joining two files without any field separator on Linux

Tags: linux, join

I have two files where fields do not have any separator. I want to join them on data with fixed position. For example:

File 1:
1234AAAAAA
1235BBBBBB
1236CCCCCC

File 2:
1234QQQQQ
1235RRRRR
1236TTTTT
1237YYYYY

Output File:

1234AAAAAAQQQQQ
1235BBBBBBRRRRR
1236CCCCCCTTTTT

Can someone suggest me a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's name files, as file1.txt and file2.txt. Since you mentioned the fields are joined at a fixed position, I assume the first field occupies the first 4 characters of each line, and that these prefixes are unique within each file. Using this fact, we could firstly find out the common prefixes across both files first using `cut`, sort them and then determine their count using `uniq -c`. This is piped finally to `awk` to display only non unique values as follows:

```
COMM_PREFIX=$(cut -c1-4 file[12].txt | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 1 {print $2}')
```

Using these prefixes, filter the corresponding line from file1 and store in a variable. Similarly, find the same pattern in file2 and store from 5th characters onwards in another variable. Use both variables to form the final output:

```
for prefix in $COMM_PREFIX; do
    FRONT=$(grep "^$prefix" file1.txt);
    BACK=$(grep "^$prefix" file2.txt | cut -c5-);
    echo "${FRONT}${BACK}";
done
```